# Get multiple posts with an array PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So here's my issue. I'm checking to see where the user is subscribed to, and here's what a result looks like

```
Array ( [0] => 11 [1] => 111 )
```

So basically they're subbed to user `11` and user `111`, so now I want to get user `11`, and `111` posts. That's basically where I'm stuck. Here's the code I used to get that array

```
$email = $call['email'];

 //Get user info
$ginfo = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email");
$ginfo->bindValue(':email', $email);
$ginfo->execute();

$id = $ginfo->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$id = $id['id'];

//Get user subs
$gsub = $con->prepare("SELECT * FROM subscriptions WHERE user_id = :id");
$gsub->bindValue(':id', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$gsub->execute();

$sub_to = $gsub->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 2);

print_r($sub_to);
```

Any help at all would be really great. I've spent hours on this, and I'm still fairly new. Thanks

My subscriptions table

```
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id     | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sub_to      | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date_subbed | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And my article table

```
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| from           | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| date_published | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| content        | text             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| title          | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| from_id        | int(11)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Please post the table structure of the `subscriptions` and `posts` tables. Unless they are very unusual, it should be possible to do this as a single join query, or `IN ()` subquery.

Comment: Something along the lines of `SELECT posts.* FROM posts WHERE user_id IN (SELECT subscribed_to FROM subscriptions WHERE user_id = :id)` (assuming the 11, 111 are in the `subscribed_to` column, whatever it may be called)

Comment: Just edited it in there. @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: Is `article.from_id` the column which identifies the user in `subscriptsion.sub_to`?

Comment: Yes it is @MichaelBerkowski

Comment: Ok, hang on a minute for a few possible solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is best to complete this as a single query, either by issuing an `INNER JOIN` between `article, subscription`, or using an `IN()` subquery .

Since `article.from_id` references `subscriptions.sub_to`, that will be your joining column.

This version will use the `:id` you already received from your earlier query.

```
SELECT
  article.*
FROM
  article
  INNER JOIN subscriptions ON article.from_id = subscriptions.sub_to
WHERE
  subscriptions.user_id = :id
```

Or if you prefer, it can be done with an `IN()` subquery instead of the join

```
SELECT
  article.*
FROM
  article
WHERE from_id IN (SELECT sub_to FROM subscriptions WHERE user_id = :id)
```

#### Better version:

However, you can eliminate the first query with an additional join:

```
SELECT
  article.*
FROM
  article
  INNER JOIN subscriptions ON article.from_id = subscriptions.sub_to
  INNER JOIN users ON subscriptions.user_id = users.id
WHERE
  users.email = :email
```

Then bind `:email` and execute:

```
$articles = $con->prepare(....);
$articles->bindValue(':email', $email);
$articles->execute();
$rows = $articles->fetchAll();
// All articles are now in $rows
print_r($rows);
```

#### Possibly even better:

Anticipating the need for poster details of the articles: If you also need the user details of the article's author, join *again* against `users`.

```
SELECT
  article.*,
  /* user details of the article authors */
  sub_authors.*
FROM
  article
  INNER JOIN subscriptions ON article.from_id = subscriptions.sub_to
  /* First join against users is to identify the subscriber by email */
  INNER JOIN users ON subscriptions.user_id = users.id
  /* additional join to get subscribed author user info */
  INNER JOIN users AS sub_authors ON subscriptions.sub_to = sub_authors.id
WHERE
  users.email = :email
```

Bind and execute `:email` as before, and now all article and author details result in `$rows`.

A final note about `SELECT article.*, sub_authors.*` above - In practice I would not actually use `*` but rather list the columns explicitly. This is important because both tables have an `id` column which won't be properly differentiated when you fetch the rows.  Better to list them with aliases like:

```
SELECT
  article.id AS article_id,
  article.title,
  article.content,
  ...,
  sub_authors.id AS author_id,
  sub_authors.name,
  ...
```

Comment: An epic answer! Thanks for all the help.